# Chrome extension and supporting older versions of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have recently started working on a chrome extension which uses manifest v3. I see a lot of APIs being different from v2.

So what happens when a user who is running an older version of chrome? As a developer, do I need to accommodate different chrome API calls based on the version that my extension is running on?

As an example this code works in the current version `chrome.runtime.getURL('logo128.png')`.

However, in the older versions `chrome.extension.getURL('logo128.png')` works.

Any help in this direction is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is there such a thing as an old version of Chrome? It's not like the old IE ecosystem where a new version was introduced with every couple of years - it's constantly being updated.

Comment: When you publish the extension in chrome web store using mv3, there is a minimum chrome version in the manifest (iirc 88), and older browser versions are incompatible and cannot install - compatibility considerations do not need to extend very far for this reason.